# ShowsMyLocationButton not showing on iOS (react-native-maps)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

The showsMyLocationButton option is not working on iOS. Initially the button didn't show on Android either, but I got it showing after implementing a hack suggested in the github issues (forcing rerender).

How can I show the button on iOS? Should I make my own button?

```
<MapView
  style={styles.map, { flex: 1, marginBottom: this.state.marginBottom }}
  onMapReady={this._onMapReady}
  initialRegion={initialRegion}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  //onPanDrag={e => console.log(e.nativeEvent)}
  followsUserLocation={true}
  showsMyLocationButton={true}
 >
```

react-native-maps: 0.21.0

react: 16.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented my own button by following this: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/209#issuecomment-350907665

Answer (score 2):

I defined provider to map like this:

```
provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
```

In MapView 
Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can also wrap `MapView` into `View`, set **style** and add `onMapReady` as follows:

```
  <View style={{paddingTop: this.state.paddingTop}}> 
    <MapView

      ...

      onMapReady={() => {
        this.setState({ paddingTop: 5 })
      }}

      ...

    </MapView>
  </View>
```

But it's a little dirty.